# How to debug System.ArgumentException in Output window?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using `.NET Core 2.2` with EF and when queries are being run against database, I see a bunch of ArgumentExceptions being logged in the **Output -> Debug** window such as:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Linq.Expressions.dll
```

The thing is my app is working perfectly fine, I get proper results and everything. I see like a hundred of these in the Visual studio's debug for no apparent reason.

Is there anyway I could find more information about these exceptions? Maybe let Visual studio break on them or something like that?

Edit: This did not happen on a different machine. I guess something bad is happening with my system and I could not tell what.

Comment: try to check `Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings->Common Language Runtime Exceptions` checkbox for the `System.ArgumentException`. Also try to uncheck `Debugging > General > Enable Just My Code`. Does it change something?

Comment: yeah, that does seem to help, it breaks on my code - thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, the answer is to enable `System.ArgumentException` at Visual Studio setting `Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings->Common Language Runtime Exceptions`.